# PHPmailer HTML table

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

my site has a form and i need it to come through as a table but i can't seem to work out how to do it.

I don't have much PHP experience so any help would be wonderful. 
This is my code.

```
<?php

require_once('phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');

$toemails = array();

$toemails[] = array(
            'email' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxx@bigpond.com', // Your Email Address
            'name' => 'xxxxxxxxx' // Your Name
        );

// Form Processing Messages
$message_success = 'We have <strong>successfully</strong> received your     Message and will get Back to you as soon as possible.';

// Add this only if you use reCaptcha with your Contact Forms
$recaptcha_secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'; // Your     reCaptcha Secret

$mail = new PHPMailer();

// If you intend you use SMTP, add your SMTP Code after this Line


if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' ) {
if( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] != '' ) {

    $name = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-name'] ) ? $_POST['template-    contactform-name'] : '';
    $email = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-email'] ) ?     $_POST['template-contactform-email'] : '';
    $phone = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-phone'] : '';
    $subject = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-subject'] : '';        
    $vesselname = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vesselname'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vesselname'] : '';
    $vesseltype1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vesseltype1'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vesseltype1'] : '';
    $vesseltype2 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vesseltype2'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vesseltype2'] : '';
    $booking1 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-booking1'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-booking1'] :'';
    $booking2 = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-booking2'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-booking2'] :'';
    $makemodel = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-makemodel'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-makemodel'] :'';
    $vlength = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vlength'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vlength'] :'';
    $vbeam = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vbeam'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vbeam'] :'';
    $vdraft = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-vdraft'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-vdraft'] :'';
    $eta = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-eta'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-eta'] :'';
    $etd = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-etd'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-etd'] :'';
    $reglocation = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-reglocation'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-reglocation'] :'';
    $regnumber = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-regnumber'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-regnumber'] :'';
    $regexp = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-regexp'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-regexp'] :'';
    $inscompany = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-inscompany'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-inscompany'] :'';
    $insnumber = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-insnumber'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-insnumber'] :'';
    $insexp = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-insexp'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-insexp'] :'';
    $cover = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-cover'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-cover'] :'';
    $elrequire = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-elrequire'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-elrequire'] :'';
    $specrequire = isset( $_POST['template-contactform-specrequire'] ) ? $_POST['template-contactform-specrequire'] :'';



    $subject = isset($subject) ? $subject : 'New Message From Contact Form';

    $botcheck = $_POST['template-contactform-botcheck'];

    if( $botcheck == '' ) {

        $mail->SetFrom( $email , $name );
        $mail->AddReplyTo( $email , $name );
        foreach( $toemails as $toemail ) {
            $mail->AddAddress( $toemail['email'] , $toemail['name'] );
        }
        $mail->Subject = $subject;

        $name = isset($name) ? "Name: $name<br><br>" : '';
        $email = isset($email) ? "Email: $email<br><br>" : '';
        $phone = isset($phone) ? "Phone: $phone<br><br>" : '';
        $booking1 = isset($booking1) ? "Booking: $booking1<br><br>" : '';
        $booking2 = isset($booking2) ? "Booking: $booking2<br><br>" : '';
        $vesselname = isset($vesselname) ? "Vessel Name: $vesselname<br>    <br>" : '';
        $vesseltype1 = isset($vesseltype1) ? "Vessel Type: $vesseltype1<br>    <br>" : '';
        $vesseltype2 = isset($vesseltype2) ? "Vessel Type: $vesseltype2<br>    <br>" : '';
        $makemodel = isset($makemodel) ? "Make and Model: $makemodel<br>    <br>" : '';
        $vlength = isset($vlength) ? "Vessel Length (m): $vlength<br><br>" : '';
        $vbeam = isset($vbeam) ? "Vessel Beam (m): $vbeam<br><br>" : '';
        $vdraft = isset($vdraft) ? "Vessel Draft (m): $vdraft<br><br>" : '';
        $eta = isset($eta) ? "Estimated Time of Arrival: $eta<br><br>" : '';
        $etd = isset($etd) ? "Estimated Time of Departure: $etd<br><br>" : '';
        $reglocation = isset($reglocation) ? "Place of Registration: $reglocation<br><br>" : '';
        $regnumber = isset($regnumber) ? "Registration Number: $regnumber<br><br>" : '';
        $regexp = isset($regexp) ? "Registration Expiry: $regexp<br><br>" : '';
        $inscompany = isset($inscompany) ? "Insurance Company: $inscompany<br><br>" : '';
        $insnumber = isset($insnumber) ? "Insurance Policy Number: $insnumber<br><br>" : '';
        $insexp = isset($insexp) ? "Insurance Expiry: $insexp<br><br>" : '';
        $cover = isset($cover) ? "Cover Incl. 10m PL: $cover<br><br>" : '';
        $elrequire = isset($elrequire) ? "Electricity Requirements: $elrequire<br><br>" : '';
        $specrequire = isset($specrequire) ? "Special Requirements: $specrequire<br><br>" : '';


        $referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? '<br><br><br>This Form was submitted from: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '';

        $body = "$name $email $phone $booking1 $booking2 $vesselname $vesseltype1 $vesseltype2 $makemodel $vlength $vbeam $vdraft $eta $etd $reglocation $regnumber $regexp $inscompany $insnumber $insexp $cover $elrequire $specrequire $referrer";

        // Runs only when File Field is present in the Contact Form
        if ( isset( $_FILES['template-contactform-file'] ) && $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK ) {
            $mail->IsHTML(true);
            $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file']['name'] );
            $mail->AddAttachment( $_FILES['template-contactform-file2']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['template-contactform-file2']['name'] );               
        }

        // Runs only when reCaptcha is present in the Contact Form
        if( isset( $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'] ) ) {
            $recaptcha_response = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];
            $response = file_get_contents( "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=" . $recaptcha_secret . "&response=" . $recaptcha_response );

            $g_response = json_decode( $response );

            if ( $g_response->success !== true ) {
                echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Captcha not Validated! Please Try Again." }';
                die;
            }
        }

        $mail->MsgHTML( $body );
        $mail->IsHTML(true)
        $sendEmail = $mail->Send();

        if( $sendEmail == true ):
            echo '{ "alert": "success", "message": "' . $message_success . '" }';
        else:
            echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Email <strong>could not</strong> be sent due to some Unexpected Error. Please Try Again later.<br /><br /><strong>Reason:</strong><br />' . $mail->ErrorInfo . '" }';
        endif;
    } else {
        echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Bot <strong>Detected</strong>.! Clean yourself Botster.!" }';
    }
} else {
    echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "Please <strong>Fill up</strong> all the Fields and Try Again." }';
}
} else {
echo '{ "alert": "error", "message": "An <strong>unexpected error</strong> occured. Please Try Again later." }';
}

?>
```

Where exactly do i add the table html and how can I implement it?

```
$body = '
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Some title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <table>
            <tr><td>Name</td><td>'.$Name.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Email</td><td>'.$email.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Phone</td><td>'.$phone.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Booking</td><td>'.$booking1.'</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Booking</td><td>'.$booking2.'</td></tr>
        </table>
        </body>
        </html>';
```

I added this table in but it turns out like 
[THis is the resultant email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7MAV.png)

Comment: where is the html? what error you have ??

Comment: No error. I need to add a HTML table to display the form.

Comment: ya please share html

Comment: where is the form to post values!

Comment: Hi, the form can be seen at www.magneticislandmarina.com.au/registration.html

I've edited the OP with the html i included in my PHP

Comment: you need to include it in your headers in the `mail()` function, simple google search

Answer (score 0):

This way add the html and check I haven't tested it.

```
$body = "<html>\n"; 
$body .= "<body style=\"font-family:Verdana, Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size:12px; color:#666666;\">\n"; 
$body = $message; 
$body .= "</body>\n"; 
$body .= "</html>\n";
```